# Class path not recognized in jenkins when using command "mvn test"

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, jenkins-pipeline

I have a project that I want to run via Jenkins and one of the steps in my JenkinsFile is like this (example):

```
stage ('Testing Stage') {
  steps {
    sh 'mvn -Dtest=com\folder1\folder1\myClass test'
  }
}
```

If I run the command in the IDE terminal, the tests run without problem but in Jenkins, the slashes are trimmed so I get an error.

How should be the syntax in the Jenkins file?

EDIT:

This is the error I get:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 37: unexpected char: '\' @ line 37, column 35.
                   sh "mvn -Dtest=com\folder1\folder1\myClass test"
                                     ^
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the following syntax:

```
sh "mvn -Dtest=com/folder1/folder1/myClass test"
```